# Singularity of a sum implies intersection of kernels?

Tags: linear-algebra

$A,B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$.

I suspect that from

$\forall \beta>0: det(A+i\beta B)=0$

it follows that

Ker(A)$\cap$ Ker(B) $\neq \{0\}$.

Any counterexamples? Ideas for proof?

Comment: Is that $i = \sqrt{-1}$? If so, it seems that from $(A+i\beta B)x = 0$ for a *single* $\beta \neq 0$ it follows that $Ax=0$ and $Bx=0$. Otherwise you'd have two *real* vectors $x,y\neq0$ with $x + iy = 0$...

Comment: @Davide: correct.

Comment: @fgp: yes, that's the i. However, why should x,y have to be real? The sum is complex, therefore x,y should be complex too, or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $A=\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&0}$ and $B=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&0}$.